# Can I access an object property just with the object name in C#?

Tags: c#, class, accessor

I have a simple class with some private properties and 2 public properties (value and type). I'm trying to find a way to call the object so that it returns its value property without having to call obj.value. I don't think it's possible.

Here's what I have in mind:

```
public class myclass {
   private int property1;
   private int property2;
   public string value;
   public string type;

   public myclass(int property1, int property2, string value, string type)
   {
       this.property1 = property1;
       this.property2 = property2;
       this.value = value;
       this.type = type;
   }
}

var obj = new myclass(1, 2, "abc", "string");
console.write(obj.value);   // returns abc
console.write(obj.type);   // returns string
console.write(obj);    // expecting abc
```

Is there a way the last line returns abc with this syntax?

You're asking why I want to achieve something like this? I am building a service with a Javascript programming module. The objects are variables and I want the users to access them by simply writing *obj* instead of *obj.value*. I need this behavior in C# (and not Javascript) because the Javascript is calling back the backend objects. If I would not have to keep the private properties that would be easy but I need to have them.

**UPDATE:**
In order to be more clear: this class is to be called by a Javascript interpreter (Jint in this case) and the class has to update the database if its value is updated, so the need for the private properties.
Here is my actual code:

```
public class SmartNumeric : ISmartVariable
{
    private Boolean _simulation;
    private Guid UserId;
    private long userKeyId;
    private long variableKeyId;
    private string Name;
    public string type
    {
        get {
            return "numeric";
        }
    }
    private float _value;
    public float value
    {
        get {
            return _value;
        }

        set {
            _value = value;

            if (!_simulation)
                new SmartCommon().SetValue(userKeyId, variableKeyId, value.ToString());
        }
    }

    public SmartNumeric(Guid UserId, long userKeyId, long variableKeyId, string Name, float value, Boolean simulation)
    {
        this.Name = Name;
        this._value = value;
        this.UserId = UserId;
        this.userKeyId = userKeyId;
        this.variableKeyId = variableKeyId;
        this._simulation = simulation;
    }
}
```

So for example a user will write its own script like

```
a = 45;
```

which is more natural in Javascript than

```
a.value = 45;
```

where a refers to a SmartNumeric object in C#. The object receives an update and this is where I need to go back to the database to update the value and need the additional properties.

Comment: Why do you need to have this behavior? There's a good chance that you are taking the wrong approach for what you need to achieve.

Comment: What you're asking for doesn't make sense.  Think about what the implications would be.  It means that you would never be able to assign `obj` to another variable.  e.g. `var obj2 = obj;` would actually assign `obj.value` to `obj2`.  In fact any expression that refers to `obj` would instead refer to `obj.value`.  So you would never be able to manipulate `obj` at all.

Comment: I understand that it does not make sense but I was wondering if some C# wizard could come up with an accessor magic trick or something. The simplest way to approach this is to create a simple object (a string) but find a way to associate other values to it. I cannot just use a separate array to keep those properties because when I access the object I don't have access to this array...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The final answer is that it cannot be done. A variable is a variable and an object is an object. Trying to go away from that and cheat will only bring other problems and I can't see how I can associate other properties to a variable without making it an object. So it'll have to be an object and the value will be accessed with obj.value.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, You can override the ToString method in the MyClass to return the value of the property you want to, like

```
public override string ToString()
{
    return this.value;
}
```

With this added to your class, the last line would print you "abc"

NOTE: what happens here is that, basically when you call `Console.WriteLine(<Something>)`, this tries to call the `ToString()` method which is there in the class Object. Now we know that the Object class is the Super Class of any class that we have. So, we override the `ToString()` method and we return whatever string we want to return from our class.

Your last line would have to be something like `Console.WriteLine(obj.ToString())`.

Hope this Helps!

Comment: That will work in the specific example given by the OP, but only because `console.write` calls ToString() when it's argument is an object.  This will not work in the general case where `obj` is used in an arbitrary expression.  Since the OP is asking "to find a way to call the object so that it returns its value property without having to call obj.value" it seems to me that the general case is what's being asked for.  This answer doesn't really answer the question.

Comment: I also need to be able to do obj1=obj2 and set the values. So I got the wrong approach on this. I need to keep properties associated without a class... Ouch... I think I'll have to fall back on obj1.value=obj2.value